# ID элемента вместо name

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как ID элемента (elem) можно подставить вместо '#name' в этой функции:

```
function Help_Side(elem) {
$('#name').slideToggle('fast');
}
```

Comment: оффтоп, 1 вопрос = 1 тема

Comment: Это так принципиально?

Comment: @vital_viza, тут обычно оффтопят так: `'я решаю задачу A, в связи с чем появились вопросы B,C и D'` :) Важно, чтобы заголовок был конкретный.

Comment: Я уже исправил
Буду учитывать это в будущем
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1

```
JS: if ($('#textarea').val()==='0') { /* code */ }
PHP: if ($_POST['textarea']==='0') { /* code */ }
```

2

```
$('#div').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({width: $(this).width()==595 ? '837px' : '595px'}, 'slow'); 
  });
```

3 см 2) только `{width: $(this).width()==0 ? '100%' : '0%'}`

4

```
function Help_Side(elem) {
  $('#'+elem).slideToggle('fast');
  }
```

Comment: ЗЫ: пользуйтесь сайтом [этим сайтом](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), там в комментариях очень часто бывают ответы на ваши вопросы)

Comment: Пардон, но английского я к сожалению не знаю